# REST application in CakePHP and angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, cakephp

I have created few applications in core php and now decided to move to CakePHP hoping to get better control over things. i was able to follow the cookbook blog example successfully but i understand angularjs well enough and love to work with it. i am following below article

```
https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-cakephp-sample/wiki/2-rest-api
```

to make an api which can reply to my angularjs calls but when i call the page 
http://localhost/posts.json at the end **i get 404 : page not found error**. not sure what is going on . I did not use the bake commands but i do have the Post model and controller well placed. Seems like there is something small thing i am missing may be in routing file . can you please help me overcoming this . Thanks for support !

pawan

Answer (score 1):

Please add your cakephp folder name where your main app folder resides in url and after that it will look like this:

http://localhost/"your cakephp folder"/posts.json

Hope it helps.

Thanks